# Assignment statement in python giving different results after changing the position of function calls

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Why does

```
is_correct =  list(llist) == list(reverse(flipped))
```

is_correct outputs False but

```
is_correct =  list(reverse(flipped)) == list(llist)
```

is_correct outputs True

I am writing the code to reverse the linked list so

1. reverse() is the function is to reverse the linked list
2. flipped and llist are the LinkedList objects shown below.

Full Code is

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
       self.head = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, value):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(value)
            return

        node = self.head
        while node.next:
            node = node.next

        node.next = Node(value)

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node.value
            node = node.next

    def __repr__(self):
        return str([v for v in self])

def reverse(linked_list):

    head = linked_list.head
    nh = head.next
    head.next = None
    while nh:
        temp = nh.next
        nh.next = head
        head = nh
        nh = temp
    linked_list.head = head
    return linked_list

llist = LinkedList()
li = [4,2,5,1,-3,0]
for value in li:
    llist.append(value)

flipped = reverse(llist)
is_correct =  list(llist) == list(reverse(flipped))
print("Pass" if is_correct else "Fail")

llist = LinkedList()
li = [4,2,5,1,-3,0]
for value in li:
    llist.append(value)

flipped = reverse(llist)
is_correct =  list(reverse(flipped)) == list(llist) 
print("Pass" if is_correct else "Fail")
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your code can't be run... Even after indenting the body of `reverse`, I get `AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: `reverse` reverses the list in-place, so `flipped` and `llist` both point to the same (now reversed) list. `list` however, makes a copy of the list as it *currently* looks, so it matters whether `list(llist)` is called before or after (as determined by its position as an argument of `==`) the second call to `reverse`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I coped it from Jupyter notebook cell so try running it in Jupyter notebook and I corrected the indenting.

Comment: @chepner reverse is a function defines by me not the pre-defined list.reverse()

Comment: Yes, I know. It still modifies your list in place: you never create any new `Node` objects, you just change the `next` attributes of each node in the original, then modified the `head` attribute of the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `reverse` is an in-place operation, your code is equivalent to

```
flipped = reverse(llist)  # two names for the same reversed list
t1 = list(llist)  # a copy of the reversed list
t2 = list(reverse(flipped)) # a copy of the re-reversed list, identical to the original
is_correct = t1 == t2  # False; one is in the original order, the other reverse order

flipped = reverse(llist)  # two names for the same reversed list
t1 = list(reverse(flipped)) # a copy of the re-reversed list
t2 = list(llist) # another copy of the re-reversed list
is_correct = t1 == t2  # True; both lists are in the original non-reversed order
```

The operands to `==` are evaluated from left to right, so whether `reverse` is called first or second makes a difference as to which `list` objects are created.